# exporting a polygon from a layer file to a file geodatabase feature in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, layer-file

I have a script that creates Service Areas(SA) using Network Analyst. I need to use the polygon of the SA later on in the script. I need to do an analysis using each resulting SA individually. The MakeFeatureLayer_management gives an error that input is not supported thus I assume I need just the polygon not the layer file.  Unfortunately,the script creates a layer file for the SA. I can't figure out how to select or create just the polygon from the layer file. Is there a "get feature from layer" or "get polygon" function? Below is the script.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 Desktop. 
My workspace is a filegeodatabase.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(PL_Fac, PL_fld) as SAcursor:
    for SArow in SAcursor:
        #print('{0}, {1}'.format(SArow[0], SArow[1]))
        SArow_new = str(SArow[1])
        whereClause = 'Add_PNTID =' +SArow_new
    # Process: Make Feature Layer
        PL_Fac_MakeLay = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(PL_Fac, PL_Fac_Lay, whereClause)
    # Process: Make Service Area Layer
        result_object = arcpy.MakeServiceAreaLayer_na(ns_RoutingNetwork_ND, "SA_Lay", impedance, "TRAVEL_FROM", "25", "SIMPLE_POLYS", "NO_MERGE", "DISKS", "NO_LINES", "OVERLAP", "NO_SPLIT", "", "", "NO_UTURNS", "'One Way';Restricted", "NO_TRIM_POLYS", "100 Meters", "NO_LINES_SOURCE_FIELDS", "USE_HIERARCHY", "")
    #Get the layer object from the result object. The service layer can now be referenced using the layer object.
        layer_object = result_object.getOutput(0)
    #Get the names of all the sublayers within the service area layer.
        sublayer_names = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(layer_object)
    #Stores the layer names that we will use later
        facilities_layer_name = sublayer_names["Facilities"]
    #Load the fire stations as facilities using default field mappings and
    #default search tolerance
        arcpy.na.AddLocations(layer_object, facilities_layer_name, PL_Fac_MakeLay, "", "")
    #Solve the service area layer
        arcpy.na.Solve(layer_object)

    #Save the solved service area layer as a layer file on disk
        layer_object.saveACopy(output_SAlay)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the SAPolygons (na class name) as the last step:

```
#Get the polygons sublayer from the service area layer
polygonsSublayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(serviceAreaLayer,
                                            naClasses["SAPolygons"])[0]

#Export the polygons sublayer as a feature class
arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(polygonsSublayer, outputPolygons)
```

Esri Help page for this sample is [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/GetNAClassNames/01mr00000004000000/)

Comment: Fantastic! I substituted the naClasses for the variable name I used sublayer_names, and it worked perfectly. Thanks very much!

Comment: Terrific. Review this page http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/ServiceAreaSolverProperties/01mr00000003000000/ if you will ever need to change the na layer settings with arcpy (think change the drive-time > solve the layer multiple times or solving multiple times at different `timeOfDay` if your ND supports historical traffic). Tons of things you can automate with `arcpy.na` module!